# Looping over JSON nested array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an API which give me a JSON file like this :
(I edited my post.i hope it can help)

```
{
"events": {

    "Israel Liga Bet South": [
        {
            "id": 47,
            "league_name": "Israel Liga Bet South",
            "home_team": "Otzma FC Holon",
            "away_team": "Beitar Ramat Gan"
        }
    ],
    "Israel Liga Bet North": [
        {
            "id": 46,
            "league_name": "Israel Liga Bet North",
            "home_team": "Bnei HaGolan VeHaGalil",
            "away_team": "Maccabi Maalot Tarshiha"
        }
    ],
    "India Bangalore Super Division": [
        {
            "id": 40,
            "league_name": "India Bangalore Super Division",
            "home_team": "ASC",
            "away_team": "South United"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

i wrote this code :

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        var events;
events = myObj.events;
Object.keys(events).forEach(function (key) {
   var inPlayEvents = events[key];
   inPlayEvents.forEach(element => {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = "my html codes";
    div.setAttribute('class', 'event-type');
    document.body.appendChild(div);
       });

});

    }


};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "json.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

but it showing me all of the matches 
I want to show the same league matches in the same `<div>`
how can I do it?
thanks for your help

Comment: This is not even valid JSON, check the curly braces and nesting...

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with compilable code a clear problem statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your JSON is wrongly formatted and it wouldn't even parse. Assuming the JSON object is like this:

```
 "Categories": {
    "cat1": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "Category_name": "cat1",
            "Name": "iphone6",
            "Details": "packed",
    }
],
"cat2": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "Category_name": "cat2",
        "Name": "GalaxyS10",
        "Details": "stock"
    }
],
"cat1": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "Category_name": "cat1",
        "Name": "iphone5s",
        "Details": "stock"         
    }
]

}
```

As for but *it showing me all of the products I want to show the same category products in the same div* you need to change the following in your iterator code:

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  var Categories;
  Categories = myObj.Categories;
  Object.keys(Categories).forEach(function(key) {
        var Products = Categories[key];
        // create your div here
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = '';
        Products.forEach(element => {
              //[! remove this] var div = document.createElement('div');
              //[! concatenate instead of assigning it] div.innerHTML = "html codes here";
              div.innerHTML += 'your html here';
              div.setAttribute('class', 'category-type');
```

Why? Because in your code you are reassigning the HTML to a new div for every product. Since you want to display all the information for all products under each category in a single div, your code would not work as expected.

Comment: Dear Abrar thanks for your reply. i changed my sample to real json file. i want to sort my details by their parents. for example: show the "Israel Liga Bet North" matches in same div and show the "India Bangalore Super Division" match in another div

Comment: @brianfohor Check out the following https://plnkr.co/edit/cNszIGTUlA6pzbhr2vit